# Framework using "Aggregate target" and "Cocoa Touch Framework". What is difference?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xcode7

I can create Framework in XCode using "Aggregate target". Also it's possible to create "Cocoa Touch Framework" in XCode 7.

What is difference between them? 
What way is preferable in new project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to support iOS < 8.o then you can't use "Cocoa Touch Framework"

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to make Cocoatouch framework.
And finally, run the script to make it universal framework.
You don't need to make it to the aggregate.

FYI, here is the script I'm using now.
I found this script from the web. (I cannot remember the source)

```js
set -e
set +u
# Avoid recursively calling this script.
if [[ $SF_MASTER_SCRIPT_RUNNING ]]
then
exit 0
fi
set -u
export SF_MASTER_SCRIPT_RUNNING=1


# Constants
SF_TARGET_NAME=${PROJECT_NAME}
UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal

# Take build target
if [[ "$SDK_NAME" =~ ([A-Za-z]+) ]]
then
SF_SDK_PLATFORM=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
echo "Could not find platform name from SDK_NAME: $SDK_NAME"
exit 1
fi

if [[ "$SF_SDK_PLATFORM" = "iphoneos" ]]
then
echo "Please choose iPhone simulator as the build target."
exit 0
fi

IPHONE_DEVICE_BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos

# Build the other (non-simulator) platform
xcodebuild -project "${PROJECT_FILE_PATH}" -target "${TARGET_NAME}" -configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" -sdk iphoneos BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR="${IPHONE_DEVICE_BUILD_DIR}/arm64" SYMROOT="${SYMROOT}" ARCHS='arm64' VALID_ARCHS='arm64' $ACTION

xcodebuild -project "${PROJECT_FILE_PATH}" -target "${TARGET_NAME}" -configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" -sdk iphoneos BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"  CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR="${IPHONE_DEVICE_BUILD_DIR}/armv7" SYMROOT="${SYMROOT}" ARCHS='armv7 armv7s' VALID_ARCHS='armv7 armv7s' $ACTION

# Copy the framework structure to the universal folder (clean it first)
rm -rf "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework"

# Smash them together to combine all architectures
lipo -create  "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/arm64/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/armv7/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}"
```

Go to project settings -> build phases and then click the plus button to add new run script.